# Invalid Entities Category And Product

Tags: symfony, entity, entity-relationship

I have 2 entities - Product and category. 
But i have in symfony dev toolbar the error - Invalid Entities 2.

The exact error is:

```
Entities Mapping

Class   Mapping errors
AppBundle\Entity\category   
The association AppBundle\Entity\category#products refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\Product#category which does not exist.
AppBundle\Entity\Product    
The association AppBundle\Entity\Product#categoryId refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\category#product which does not exist.here
```

I've tried many times fix the relastion following symfony docs, but it dosn't works.

So, please, tell were am i wrong....

Here are my 2 entities:

Product

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sku", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $sku;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\category", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    private $categoryId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\File(
     *      maxSize="5242880",
     *      mimeTypes = {
     *          "image/png",
     *          "image/jpeg",
     *          "image/jpg",
     *          "image/gif",
     *      }
     * )
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @var decimal
     */
    private $percent;
    /**
     * @var decimal
     */
    private $endPrice;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set sku
     *
     * @param string $sku
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setSku($sku)
    {
        $this->sku = $sku;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sku
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSku()
    {
        return $this->sku;
    }

    /**
     * Set categoryId
     *
     * @param integer $categoryId
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCategoryId($categoryId)
    {
        $this->categoryId = $categoryId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get categoryId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->categoryId;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {

        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function getPercent()
    {
        return $this->percent;
    }

    /**
     * @param decimal $percent
     */
    public function setPercent($percent)
    {
        if(null != $percent) {
            $this->percent = $percent;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function getEndPrice()
    {
        return $this->endPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @param decimal $endPrice
     */
    public function setEndPrice($endPrice)
    {
        $this->endPrice = $endPrice;
    }

}
```

.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
category

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\categoryRepository")
 */
class category
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="parent", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product" , mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param integer $parent
     *
     * @return category
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return category
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->id."";
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $products
     */
    public function setProducts($products)
    {
        $this->products = $products;
    }

}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing in Product entity this

```
private $categoryId;
```

By this

```
private $category;
```

Don't forget to change the getter & setter

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\category", inversedBy="product")
```

to this:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
```

and this:

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product" , mappedBy="category")
```

to this:

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product" , mappedBy="category")
```